# Seeking a cleaner NLog conditional layout

Tags: nlog

I wish to differentiate my log entries depending on whether they contain an exception. I'm writing to the Windows Event Log, so I've opted to place my 'column' names at left, like so:

```
Method:     PowerDown.Tests.MainTest.TestLogging()
Message:    This is an NLog test entry.
```

This is rendered when the event doesn't contain an exception. When the event contains an exception, however, I alter my layout to produce this instead:

```
Method:     PowerDown.Tests.MainTest.TestExceptionLogging()
Exception:  System.Exception: This is an NLog test exception.
   at PowerDown.Tests.MainTest.TestExceptionLogging() in D:\Dev\Customers\OIT\Active\PowerDown\Application\PowerDown.Tests\MainTest.vb:line 17
```

I have all of this working, but the code feels rather kludgy and overcomplicated. Is there a way to accomplish this natively, without the custom layout renderer?

(Note: I wish to retain my runtime-based NLog configuration, as below. Configuration files aren't suitable for the present environment.)

**Code:**

```
Public Shared Function GetLogger(Name As String) As Logger
  Dim oBuilder As StringBuilder
  Dim oConfig As LoggingConfiguration
  Dim oTarget As EventLogTarget
  Dim sLayout As String
  Dim oRule As LoggingRule

  LayoutRenderer.Register("event-log", Function(LogEvent)
                                         If LogEvent.Exception Is Nothing Then
                                           sLayout = $"Message:{vbTab}{LogEvent.Message}{vbCrLf}"
                                         Else
                                           With LogEvent.Exception
                                             sLayout = $"Exception:{vbTab}{ .GetType.FullName}: { .Message}{vbCrLf}{ .StackTrace}{vbCrLf}"
                                           End With
                                         End If

                                         Return sLayout
                                       End Function)

  oBuilder = New StringBuilder
  oBuilder.Append($"Method:{vbTab}{vbTab}${{callsite}}()${{newline}}")
  oBuilder.Append("${event-log}")

  oTarget = New EventLogTarget("Event") With {
    .Layout = oBuilder.ToString,
    .Source = Name
  }

  oRule = New LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, oTarget)

  oConfig = New LoggingConfiguration
  oConfig.LoggingRules.Add(oRule)
  oConfig.AddTarget(oTarget)

  LogManager.Configuration = oConfig

  Return LogManager.GetLogger(Name)
End Function
```

Comment: Should the config created in C# or is a nlog.config also an option?

Comment: @Julian — C# or VB is fine... I can translate. In the end I won't be using an `nlog.config` file, but I might be able to port the contents of one into runtime code. I'm still a bit new at NLog, but I should be able to do that. In any case I'm kind of thinking that the solution might be in the layout string syntax, so it may not matter. In my searching I haven't come across any `if-then-else` conditional syntax for layout strings, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's called `${when}` in NLog. See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer and also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/WhenEmpty-Layout-Renderer

Comment: @Julian — This works. Would you make it an answer so I can accept it.